# Wrong computation Number

Tags: arduino-nano, interrupt

im trying to make a speedometer with arduino Nano Board but when i use interrupt im getting "strange" number on variables `t1` or `t2` going under 0 there is the code:

```
volatile int impulsi =  0;
int impulsiOld = 0;
volatile int appoggio = 0;
//static int inizioDiNuovo = 0;
volatile unsigned int deltaT[3];
long t1=0;
long t2=0;  




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(0, definisciTempi, RISING);

}

void loop() {

  Serial.println(impulsi);
  if (impulsi == impulsiOld || impulsi > impulsiOld)
  {
    ;
  }
  //Serial.print("N IMPULSI: ");
  //Serial.println(impulsi);
  if (appoggio == 3) {
    appoggio = 0;
    Serial.print("DELTA T 0 : ");
    Serial.println(deltaT[0]);
    Serial.print("DELTA T 1 : ");
    Serial.println(deltaT[1]);
    Serial.print("DELTA T 2 : ");
    Serial.println(deltaT[2]);

    t1 = (deltaT[1] - deltaT[0]);
    if (t1 == 0) {
      t1 = 1;
    }
    t2 = (deltaT[2] - deltaT[1]);
    if (t2 == 0) {
      t2 = 1;
    }
    int t = t1 + t2;

    Serial.print("TEMPO T1 ");
    Serial.println(t1);
    Serial.print("TEMPO T2 ");
    Serial.println(t2);

  }

}


void definisciTempi() {
  impulsi++;
  switch(appoggio){

    case 2:
    //Serial.println("ASSEGNO DELTA T 2");
    deltaT[2] = millis();
    //Serial.println(deltaT[2]);
    appoggio = 3;
    break;

    case 1:
    //Serial.println("ASSEGNO DELTA T 1");
    deltaT[1] = millis();
    appoggio = 2;
    break;

    case 0:
    //Serial.println("ASSEGNO DELTA T 0");
    deltaT[0] = millis();
    appoggio = 1;
    break;

  }
}
```

how suggest i changed

```
unsigned int t1=0; unsigned int t2=0; into `long t1=0; long t2=0;`
```

output on Serial now have negative number it's for the interrupt??:

```
DELTA T 0 : 8785
DELTA T 1 : 8666
DELTA T 2 : 8706
TEMPO T1 40
TEMPO T2 -119  <------how 8706-8666= -119 ?
```

this is my pulse generator code:

```
const int pin = 2;
void setup() {
  pinMode(pin,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
 digitalWrite(pin,HIGH);
 delay(40);
 digitalWrite(pin,LOW);
 delay(40);
}
```

Comment: appoggio Isn't defined as volatile. All variables that get changed in the interrupt, and used in the main loop need to be volatile.

Comment: thanks i made `appoggio` volatile but don't change the result , every time negative number , thanks

Comment: Move "appoggio = 0;" to after al the serial.prints.

Comment: After you set appoggio = 0; and interrupt might fire, and change the variables you are currently working on.

Comment: What will happens if you get an interrupt between printing the deltas and calculating the t values? You'll end up with the t values being calculated with the new delta values (or half with the old ones, half with the new ones) . You need to disable interrupts, make a copy of the delta values and then re-enable them. You then base all your outputs and calculations on the copies.

Comment: Oddly, with the delta numbers shown: `deltaT[1] - deltaT[0] == -119` and `deltaT[2] - deltaT[1] == 40`. In the output it appears that t1 and t2 have swapped values.

Comment: Andrew THANKS for your reply, now i just disable the interrupt for make some compute operation without problem, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interrupt may be triggering between the Serial.print and the actual calculations, as stated by @Andrew.

Evidence supporting that fact is that your deltas are recorded in order 0, 1, 2 (ie: delta 0 < delta 1 < delta 2), However in the example output delta 0 is larger than delta 2, which suggests that a new round of delta recordings had started but not yet completed.

Updating this section as follows should fix the issue:

```
if (appoggio == 3) {

  noInterrupts(); // Disable interrupts while calculating

  appoggio = 0;
  Serial.print("DELTA T 0 : ");
  Serial.println(deltaT[0]);
  Serial.print("DELTA T 1 : ");
  Serial.println(deltaT[1]);
  Serial.print("DELTA T 2 : ");
  Serial.println(deltaT[2]);

  t1 = (deltaT[1] - deltaT[0]);
  if (t1 == 0) {
    t1 = 1;
  }
  t2 = (deltaT[2] - deltaT[1]);
  if (t2 == 0) {
    t2 = 1;
  }
  int t = t1 + t2;

  Serial.print("TEMPO T1 ");
  Serial.println(t1);
  Serial.print("TEMPO T2 ");
  Serial.println(t2);

  interrupts(); // re-enable interrupts

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int t1=0;
unsigned int t2=0;
```

Integers on an 8 bit system can only store 16 bits of data. For `unsigned` that is 0 - 2<sup>16</sup>-1, or 0 - 65535.

Make them `unsigned long` and they can store 0 - 2<sup>32</sup>-1, or 0 - 4294967295.

Also, since they are `unsigned`, any negative value will *wrap around* to the maximum again. An `unsigned` can't store a negative value.

Comment: I'm simulating the pulse with another arduino board, how an impulse timing be negative? i have setted the time to 40ms for each pulse(sorry for my english)

Comment: now i make the change to` unsigned int` to` unsigned long` but now this the output: `DELTA T 0 : 3269
DELTA T 1 : 3309
DELTA T 2 : 3349
TEMPO T1 4294967096
TEMPO T2 40`

Comment: You may well be suffering from a lack of critical sections which I mentioned in your previous question.